# How to specify file name using dataFrameWriter when saving parquet file in delta lake format

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, delta-lake

having the following code

```
 df.write.format('delta').save(some_path)
```

how can I set the file name e.g `foo.parquet` ?
I tried :

```
df.write
.format('delta')
.option("filename","foo")
.save(some_path)
```

but it didn't work. is it possible ?

Comment: you mean the names of the parquet files inside the delta catalog? Because you can just do `.save(some_path + "/foo.parquet")`

Comment: @AlexOtt i tried it it just creates the directory with that name

Comment: This is how Spark works...